# Recurring Label Change Without NSDate Formatter

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

Okay so i have a problem. In xcode every time a full day passes i want the label to change. For instance if the time is 24:00:00 then i want the label to change from Monday to Tuesday; and then from tuesday to Wednesday and so on and so forth. This is all i have so far

```
if ([timev2.text isEqualToString: @"24:00:00"]) {
    [number setText:@"Tuesday"];
```

I can't use the statement

```
if([timev2 isEqualToString: @'48:00:00']){
   [number setText:@"wednesday"];
```

Because I'm using `NSDaterFormatter`.
Can anyone tell me how to do this or how to edit my code to make it work?

Comment: C++? ***Where, seriously?***

Comment: @H2CO3 Sorry my mistake

Comment: Look up the format specifiers. It can give you the full name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification to be notified when the system clock changes to a new day while your app is running.

You can use NSDateFormatter to print weekday names. Format specifier "EEEE" or "cccc" should work. (Weekday names have two forms in some languages; the correct one to use depends on your context. http://cldr.unicode.org/translation/date-time)

Comment: thanks! your answer added a-lot more info to the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In NSDateFormatter Object set the date format to "EEEE" where you will get the day of a week. and You can display in label.

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
NSString *weekDay=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

weekday is the day you wanted..Happy Coding...